# Conditional aggregation by regarding missing data in R

Tags: r, time-series, aggregation, missing-data

I am trying to aggregate hourly data to daily data in R. The problem is missing values. I want to consider a threshold for the number of missing values before the aggregation. ***If the number of missing values is more than two in the given day***, **DO NOT** **compute the daily average and fill that day with NA**. 
My dummy data are daily data for the first day of 2005.

```
          day hour amount amount2
1  2005-01-01    0      1       1
2  2005-01-01    1      2      NA
3  2005-01-01    2      4       4
4  2005-01-01    3      5       5
5  2005-01-01    4     11      NA
6  2005-01-01    5      4      NA
7  2005-01-01    6     NA      NA
8  2005-01-01    7      2       2
9  2005-01-01    8      4       4
10 2005-01-01    9      2       2
11 2005-01-01   10      4      20
12 2005-01-01   11     12      12
13 2005-01-01   12     13      13
14 2005-01-01   13      7       7
15 2005-01-01   14      4       4
16 2005-01-01   15     12      12
17 2005-01-01   16      4       4
18 2005-01-01   17     12      12
19 2005-01-01   18      5       5
20 2005-01-01   19     11      11
21 2005-01-01   20      4       4
22 2005-01-01   21     12      12
23 2005-01-01   22     13      13
24 2005-01-01   23      7       7
```

What I already got

```
  agg
             day amount amount2
    1 2005-01-01    6.9     7.7
```

what I want to have

```
agg
             day amount amount2
    1 2005-01-01    6.9     NA
```

Because the number of missing values in the column *amount2* is more than two, I want its daily average filled by NA (not 7.7) while it is calculated for the column *amount* (6.9).
I have used the function "aggregate" from "stats" library.

```
library(stats)
amount=(c(1,2,4,5,11,4,NA,2,4,2,4,12,13,7,4,12,4,12,5,11,4,12,13,7))
amount2=(c(1,NA,4,5,NA,NA,NA,2,4,2,20,12,13,7,4,12,4,12,5,11,4,12,13,7))
day=c("2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01",
"2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01",
"2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01",
 "2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01",
 "2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01","2005-01-01")
hour=seq(0,23)
date=data.frame(day,hour)
dummy=cbind(date,amount,amount2)
agg <- aggregate(cbind(amount,amount2) ~ day, dummy, mean)
```

Comment: the way your code is currently written you're computing the mean of `amount` only across observations for which `amount2` is not `NA`, is this intentional? E.g. `mean(amount, na.rm=T)` is ~6.74 not 6.9.

Comment: "the mean of amount only across observations for which amount2 is not NA", that is my problem. As written above, I want it to be filled with NA. Regarding na.action, you are right. At moment my main issue is making the threshold for the number of missing values.

Comment: Try something like `apply(dummy[,3:4], 2, function(x){ifelse(sum(is.na(x))<2, mean(x, na.rm=T), NA)})`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It works for one day. I am wondering if I can pass this into aggregate to be applied for all days.

Comment: Maybe the best way is to put your code into a loop. Thanks.

Comment: @SeyedOmidNabavi, if you accept a `dplyr` solution, then you can also write `dummy %>% group_by(day) %>% summarise_at(vars(amount, amount2), function(x) ifelse(sum(is.na(x))<2, mean(x, na.rm = T), NA))`.

Comment: Otherwise, you can do `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dummy, dummy$day), function(y) apply(y[,3:4], 2, function(x){ifelse(sum(is.na(x))<2, mean(x, na.rm=T), NA)})))`

Comment: @hpesoj626 thanks for your reply. It works like a charm.